# Создание кнопок со скругленными краями Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Появилась задача сделать красивый интерфейс при помощи змеи. Есть ли в Tkinter возможность редактировать стиль кнопок и остального(форму кнопок)

Comment: Можно рисовать кнопку нужного вида на Canvas, и использовать Canvas как кнопку.

Answer (score 1):

Почитай Николай Анатольевич Прохоренок - Python 3 и PyQt
Там хорошо просвещается созданию интерфейса, округлению, прозрачности и др

Если лень читать, вот ответ:

Очень простой способ сделать закругленную кнопку в tkinter - использовать изображение.

Сначала создайте образ того, что вы хотите, чтобы кнопка выглядела как сохранить его как.png и удалить внешний фон, чтобы он закруглялся, как показано ниже:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPdrY.png
```

Затем вставьте изображение с помощью кнопки PhotoImage следующим образом:

```
self.loadimage = tk.PhotoImage(file="rounded_button.png")
self.roundedbutton = tk.Button(self, image=self.loadimage)
self.roundedbutton["bg"] = "white"
self.roundedbutton["border"] = "0"
self.roundedbutton.pack(side="top")
```

Убедитесь, что используется border="0" и рамка кнопки будет удалена.

Я добавил `self.roundedborder["bg"] = "white"` чтобы фон кнопки был таким же, как и окно Tkinter.

Большая часть состоит в том, что вы можете использовать любую фигуру, которая вам нравится, а не только обычные формы кнопок.

Comment: А без использования картинок?

Comment: Сложно назвать такой способ правильным

Comment: К сожелению именно в Tkinter я не нашел другого способа. Либо сделать в фотошопе картину с округлением, сохранить в png, вставить её в программу, либо переходите на Kivy, если не ошибаюсь. Нашел что мог.

Answer (score 0):

Решение просто. Я переписан программу на PyQt(а именно через Qt Designer переделал юи), а в qt можно использовать css для работы с стилем

Comment: Если бы вам нужно было именно на tkinter, а вам дали ответ на PyQt, как бы вы к этому отнеслись? Так что можно считать, что это не является ответом на вопрос.